# Show how many results query have in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I do have a search form on a page which search records from a table in my database. I want to show how many results each query gives us. All this is written in codeigniter.

All my code on that page:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function index() {
  $data['title'] = "Welcome | randomsite";
  $data['html'] = "";
  if($this->input->post()) {
   $uq = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('query'));
   if(trim($uq) != "") {
    $searchBy = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('searchBy'));
    $searchByJSON = json_encode(array(1 => "Email", 2 => "Username", 3 => "IP", 4 => "FullName", 5 => "Phone"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
    if(isset(json_decode($searchByJSON)->$searchBy)) {
     $start = microtime(true);
     $this->db->from('Databases');
     $rs = $this->db->get()->result();
     $end = microtime(true);
     $data['html'] .= "Search completed in: " . ($end - $start) . " seconds.<p></p>";
     foreach($rs as $row) {
      $this->db->distinct();
      $this->db->select('Username, Password, Email, FullName, IP, Phone, salt');
      $this->db->from('Accounts');
      $this->db->where(json_decode($searchByJSON)->$searchBy, $uq);
      $this->db->where('DatabaseID', $row->ID);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       if($searchBy == 5 && $query->row()->Phone == 0) {
        break;
       }
       $resultsHTML = "";
       foreach($query->result() as $qr) {
        $resultsHTML .= "<div class='card-block-results' style='table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word;'><table class='table table-hover' style='font-size:13px;'>";
        foreach($qr as $key => $value) {
         if(!empty($value)) {
          if($key == "FullName") {
           $key = "Full Name";

          }
          $resultsHTML .= "<tr><td>" . $key . ": " . $value . "</td></tr>";
         }
        }
        $resultsHTML .= "</table></div>"; 
       }
       $data['html'] .= $row->Website . " has: <b style='color:lime;'>" . $query->num_rows() . "</b> result(s) found. This data was hacked on approximately " . $row->Date . ". <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' style='margin-bottom:5px;' id='button" . $row->ID . "'>view results</button><div id='results" . $row->ID . "' style='display:none;'><div class='card card-outline-primary' style='margin-bottom:10px;text-align:left;margin-top:5px;'><div class='card-header card-primary'>Results</div>" . $resultsHTML . "</div></div><script type='text/javascript'>$('#button" . $row->ID . "').click(function() { $(this).hide(); $('#results" . $row->ID . "').show(); });</script><br>";
      }
     }
     if($data['html'] == "Search completed in: " . ($end - $start) . " seconds.<p></p>") {
      $data['html'] .= "No results found!<p></p>Are you searching in the right fields? Searching for an email in the phone number field will not work.<br>Make sure first and last names are correct. Example: Mike Tyson";
     }
     $data['html'] .= "<br><br><br>";
     $this->db->from('Lookups');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     $new_lookup = $query->row()->Number + 1;
     $qdata = array(
      "Number" => $new_lookup
     );
     $this->db->update('Lookups', $qdata);
    }
   } else {
   $data['html'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Please enter something in your query before searching!</div>';
   
   }
  }
  $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
 }

}
```

So how can I add that into every time someone is searching? Like 'Query had x results.'

Like this:

[image]

I searched on many different sites about this but I couldn't find anything for my specific question.

Answer (score 1):

you have already used it in your code,

```
$query->num_rows()
```

will give you the number of rows u get from the query.

Comment: Why is it not displaying then on my site?

Comment: I am using it for displaying how many record that was found in a specific added database but I want to show total how many rows.

Comment: try this, `count($query->result())`

Comment: replace `$query->num_rows() . "</b> result(s) found. This data was hacked on approximately "` to 
`count($query->num_rows()) . "</b> result(s) found. This data was hacked on approximately "`

Answer (score 0):

i think this is abusing a framework like CI - i give you some insights in to this framework - if you are willing to learn, study this piece of code because 
you nearly don't use any of his built in functionality

in my opinion you've to restructure your code to such an extent that you don't even recognize your previous attempt ;)

i'll try to give you a hunch - but in order to understand - you've to work with this code

put in your models folder the following models

**Database Model**

```
class Database_model extends CI_Model
{

    private $objCollection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->objCollection = new Database_Collection();
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');
        $this->db->from('Databases');
        $this->objCollection->append($this->db->get()->result());
        $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

        $this->objCollection->queryTime =  $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');

        return $this->objCollection;
    }

}


class Database_Collection extends ArrayObject
{
    public $queryTime = 0;
}
```

**Accounts Model**

```
class Accounts_model extends CI_Model
{

    private $objCollection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->objCollection = new Accounts_Collection();
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

        $this->db
            ->distinct()
            ->select('Username, Password, Email, FullName, IP, Phone, salt')
            ->from('Accounts');

        $this->objCollection->append($this->db->get()->result());
        $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

        $this->objCollection->queryTime =  $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');

        return $this->objCollection;
    }

}


class Accounts_Collection extends ArrayObject
{
    public $queryTime = 0;
}
```

**Search Model**

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $strSearchQuery = "";

    public function getSearchObject()
    {
        if ($this->isValidSearch())
        {
            $this->load->model("Database_Model");
            $this->load->model("Accounts_Model");

            $objSearch = new Search;

            $objDBCollection = $this->Database_Model->getCollection();

            foreach($objDBCollection AS $objItem)
            {
                $this->db
                    ->where("DatabaseID", $objItem->ID)
                    ->where($this->input->post("searchBy"), $this->strSearchQuery);

                $objItem->collection = $this->Accounts_Model->getCollection();

            }

            $objSearch->addResultCollection($objDBCollection);

            return $objSearch;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isValidSearch()
    {
        $strSearchQuery = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('query'));
        $this->strSearchQuery = trim($strSearchQuery);
        if (empty($this->strSearchQuery))   return false;

        $arrValidSearchCriteria = array("Email", "Username", "IP", "FullName", "Phone");
        return (in_array($this->input->post("searchBy"),arrValidSearchCriteria));

    }
}

class Search
{
    public $queryTime = 0;

    private $objCollection;

    public function addResultCollection(Database_Collection $objCollection)
    {
        $this->objCollection = $objCollection;
    }

    public function getRenderedTime()
    {
        if ($this->queryTime == 0)
        {
            $this->queryTime += $this->objCollection->queryTime;

            foreach($this->objCollection AS $objItem)
            {
                if (isset($objItem->collection)
                {
                    $this->queryTime += $objItem->collection->queryTime;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->queryTime;
    }
    public function getCountSearchResults()
    {
        if (!$this->countSearchResults)
        {
            $this->countSearchResults = 0;

            foreach($this->objCollection AS $objItem)
            {
                if (isset($objItem->collection)
                {
                    $this->countSearchResults += $objItem->collection->count();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->countSearchResults;
    }
}
```

**your controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->load->model("Search_model");

        $data['title'] = "Welcome | randomsite";

        if ($this->Search_model->isValidSearch()
        {
            $objSearch = $this->Search_model->getSearchObject();
            $arrViewData = array("objSearch" => $objSearch);
            $this->load->view("list-search", $arrViewData);

        }


    }
}
```

pS: maybe there are some typos because i just wrote it down